# get_post() is not returning correct value

Tags: wp-query, wpdb, get-post

I have a post and i need to update its post_parent. So i have used below code to update the post_parent value. Old post_parent is 844 and using query i have updated the value to 370 using below:

```
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";
    $add_plan_to_team = $wpdb->update( $table_name, array( 'post_parent' => '370' ), array('ID'=> '84887'));
    // UPDATE wp_posts SET post_parent=370 WHERE ID=84887
```

In next line , i need to get the post and then perform some functions.  I am doing it like this

```
     $post = get_post( 84887 );
```

But instead of returning updated values, i am getting the old post_parent value in return. Like below

```
WP_Post Object
(
    [ID] => 84887
    [post_author] => 2
    [post_date] => 2020-02-27 10:55:11
    [post_date_gmt] => 2020-02-27 10:55:11
    [post_content] => 
    [post_title] => MyTeam
    [post_excerpt] => 
    [post_status] => publish
    [comment_status] => closed
    [ping_status] => closed
    [post_password] => 
    [post_name] => allus-cu
    [to_ping] => 
    [pinged] => 
    [post_modified] => 2020-08-24 19:03:02
    [post_modified_gmt] => 2020-08-24 19:03:02
    [post_content_filtered] => 
    [post_parent] => 844   // This value is not correct. This should be 370
    [guid] => https://train.localdev.com/?post_type=wc_memberships_team&p=84887
    [menu_order] => 0
    [post_type] => wc_memberships_team
    [post_mime_type] => 
    [comment_count] => 0
    [filter] => db
)
```

I have checked in Database and in database, post_parent value is updated one.

Complete Code in all together:

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";
$add_plan_to_team = $wpdb->update( $table_name, array( 'post_parent' => '370' ), array('ID'=> '84887'));

if($add_plan_to_team){
    $post = get_post( $team_id, 'OBJECT', 'db' );
    echo '<h1> team_updated </h1>';
    print_r($post);            
}
```

Please tell me how can i fix it.

Comment: Judging from your comment below, this looks like an XY problem, where you needed to update posts inside the `save_posts` hook but ran into recursion, so you devised a solution of using WPDB directly and it didn't work. Then, rather than ask how to avoid recursion in `save_post`, you instead asked how to fix your broken fix. Is this correct? There is a canonical solution for your problem, but I can't post it because that's not what you asked

Comment: Yes thats correct. To avoid recursion in save post, i have used wpdb query directly. You can share the correct way as well

Comment: Ah I see. I can't answer with that as it's not what you asked, it would mean the answer would make no sense to anybody looking. I recommend asking a new question specifically about your original problem, as it's not the same question

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you update posts. Because you used raw SQL to do it, none of the filters or actions fired, and none of `WP_Cache` was updated, so it'll return an old version of the post it fetched earlier when you call `get_post`.

Instead, if you want to update a post, use `wp_insert_post` and pass the posts ID parameter.

E.g.

```php
$result = wp_insert_post( [
    'ID' => 84887,
    'post_parent' => 370,
] );
```

Additional notes:

- Don't use raw SQL to do things if there's an API ( for this there were several )
- Don't hardcode post IDs, use slugs if you must hardcode anything. All it takes is an accidental post deletion and the code has to be changed at least with slugs you can rename a post and it works again ( and it won't work if you migrate the site with hardcoded numbers )
- numbers aren't strings, use `5` not `'5'` especially when using SQL functions

Comment: Hello, I cannot use wp_insert_post() or wp_update_post() because i am inside save_post_{$post->post_type} hook and wp_update_post() re-triggers the save_pos_{$post->post_type}  hook and instead of moving to next line, pointer moves to the very first line in the same function. I need to update value in DB without triggering save_post_{$post->post_type}

Comment: Secondly hard code values mentioned about are just for reference. I am inside a loop and all values are dynamic there. No hard coded values are used.

Comment: That's not true, you can with the right safeguards, and it was a super important piece of info you left out. Can you provide more context? It sounds like you tried to make the question generic/abstract but went too far. Remember, i'm not giving you a solution to your problem, I'm giving you an answer to your question, your question made no mention of save post, so update it with the relevant info

Comment: @OptimumCreative this may not be the solution to your problem, but it is the answer to your question. I'd recommend asking a new question for your original problem